# Why can't I use MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to use MapView so I get SHA1 fingerprint and also I get my apikey but in my MainActivity.java file when I import com.google.android.maps.MapView it shows that this package is not available so I don't know where I'm making a mistake

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapviewexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapviewexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my apikey" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my activity_main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.mapviewexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

As you see above when I import this

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
```

and others it shows that these packages are not available. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or some other IDE? Have you targeted Android or the Google APIs?

Comment: Yes i'm using eclipse and i'v targetted what are you talking about.

Comment: You have to target the Google APIs and not Android when you want a project to have Maps...

Comment: @user1833334 you are using google api v2 right?

Answer (score 1):

Change your project build target ,It may be probably standard android platform
instead you should select Google-API project .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
                           uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
 in your manifest and also the sdk should be google-api, go to your project properties and then android and select any google api from there 
and extends your class with Mapactivity.

Answer (score 0):

MapView is always shown in `MapActivity`. you are using `Activity`. try Using `MapActivity` and google api emulator.
`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`  put it in your application tag

Comment: The Problem is there when i use MapActivity it shows that it is not available.I'm refering to that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all **GET THE GOOGLE MAPS API KEY**

To allow you to show maps on your application, Google Maps API needs to identify you and your application (even if you are simply developing). For this you need the API Key for the Android platform.
You can get this by creating an md5 checksum of the debug certificate for you map application (in this case the tutorial).
Find your debug.keystore at
* Windows Vista: C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
* Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
Then use the Keytool (found at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin) and get the md5 checksum by executing this:
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore “C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\debug.keystore” -storepass android -keypass android


after that start coding and be sure **you select the relevant version of Google APIs (in case there’s a newer version by the time you are working on this).**

**strings.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloGoogleMaps!</string>
 <string name="app_name">Hello,GoogleMaps</string>
 <string name="mapskey">YOUR API KEY</string>
</resources>

**main.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/mapview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="YOUR API KEY"
/>

**AndroidManifest.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.HelloGoogleMaps2"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
 <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps2" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>


**HelloGoogleMaps2.java**

    public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(30443769,-91158458);
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Laissez les bon temps rouler!", "I'm in Louisiana!");

 GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(17385812,78480667);
 OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Namashkaar!", "I'm in Hyderabad, India!");

 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);

 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }
}

    **HelloItemizedOverlay.java**

    public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{
 private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 private Context mContext;

 public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
 {
 super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
 mContext = context;
 }

 public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
 {
 mOverlays.add(overlay);
 populate();
 }
 @Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
 {
 return mOverlays.get(i);
 }
 @Override
 public int size()
 {
 return mOverlays.size();
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean onTap(int index)
 {
 OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
 dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
 dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
 dialog.show();
 return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and i'm refering to that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api i'm doing what it says

Comment: @user1833334 similar process,

Comment: @anshika comment was not for you mistake i wrote it here, it was for user1833334 as he said "it shows that this package is not available"

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure your key work. Try it with google example first
2. You must forward all the [Activity life cycle methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview).

> ```
> @Override
> public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
>     mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     try {
>        MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
>     } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
>        e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>  }
>
> @Override
> public void onPause() {
>     super.onPause();
>     mapView.onPause();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onResume() {
>    super.onResume();
>    mapView.onResume();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
>     mapView.onDestroy();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What I don't see is anything about putting the library that contains com.google.android.gms.maps and other classes on your class path.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer given by @gaurav-jain Android projects don't automatically include Google Maps. You need to target the appropriate version of the Google APIs and not the appropriate version of Android.

[image: project properties]

Here you can see an Android project in Eclipse. I right-clicked the project and chose properties and then clicked into the Android section. You can see that the targeted version is Android 4.2.

In this project Google Maps will not be available. I would need to change my target to Google APIs 4.2 if I wanted to use maps.

If you don't see Google APIs in your list then you would need to use the SDK manager to download and intall the required versions